# How to implement "if-else" condition which involves multiplication by a number on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm converting a logic into python and need some help.

if column A [currency] == CAD then I need to multiply all the columns (col D, E,G) by 0.7 which are having string "cost" in their names and if column A [currency] == USD then there will be no change for col D, E and G.

Please note that this is a sample and there are more than 50 columns having cost in their names.

I tried following code but didn't work:

```
cad_cols = df.filter(regex='cost').columns
df[cad_cols] = np.where(df['currency']=="CAD",*0.7)



currency    name    address prim_cost   sec_cost    sales   overall_cost
cad     a   x       1       8       1   4
cad     b   x       5       3       2   3
usd     d   x       7       2       3   6
usd     e   x       9       4       4   7
```

Comment: Idea: Get the header/column names, then filter the names for ending with _cost, use Pandas indexing mechanism to select a named column, apply the multiplication on the column.

Comment: Images of data are discouraged. Please copy/paste data as text.

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.

Comment: [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `loc` access:

```
df.loc[df['currency']=='cad', df.columns.str.endswith('_cost')] *= 0.7
```

Output:

```
  currency name  prim_cost  sales  total_cost
0      cad    a        0.7      1         2.8
1      cad    b        3.5      2         2.1
2      usd    c        7.0      3         6.0
3      usd    d        9.0      4         7.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter select the columns

```
df.loc[df.currency==1,['p','s','o']]*=0.7
```